# Linux fonts missing. Stackoverflow code samples displaying completely blank

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts

Help.
 I cannot view code samples in stackoverflow. I am running ubuntu 14.04 and mozilla firefox. Even as I am typing this, I cannot see what I am typing in the body box, allthough I can see the preview output. There seems to be an issue with my linux fonts installation, probably   not a browser issue.
Could someone tell me which font the code samples use, as this will help me investigate further.

Apologies for the bad format of this post. It is difficult when  you can't see what you are typing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the issue relates to mozilla firefox. The Fonts are appearing in chrome.
Update: the problem was resolved by reinstalling firefox.